# How should I be cleaning up KnockoutJS ViewModels?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a single-page app where the user pages through lists of items. Each item, in turn, has a list of items.

An observable array is updated with new items from the server retrieved via an AJAX request. This all works fine.

Unfortunately after a few pages, the number of operations performed (and the amount of memory used in browsers like FireFox and IE8) keeps going up. I've tracked it down to the fact that elements in my observable array are not being cleaned up properly and are actually still in memory, even though I've replaced the items in my observable array with new data.

I've created a [small example](http://jsfiddle.net/gWVDu/6/) that replicates the problem I'm seeing:

**HTML:**

```
<p data-bind="text: timesComputed"></p>
<button data-bind="click: more">MORE</button>
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'items-template', foreach: items }">
</ul>

<script id="items-template">
    <li>
        <p data-bind="text: text"></p>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'subitems-template', foreach: subItems }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>

<script id="subitems-template">
    <li>
        <p data-bind="text: text"></p>
    </li>
</script>
```

**JavaScript/KnockoutJS ViewModels:**

```
var subItemIndex = 0;

$("#clear").on("click", function () {
  $("#log").empty();
});

function log(msg) {
  $("#log").text(function (_, current) {
    return current + "\n" + msg;
  });
}
function Item(num, root) {
  var idx = 0;

  this.text = ko.observable("Item " + num);
  this.subItems = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.addSubItem = function () {
    this.subItems.push(new SubItem(++subItemIndex, root));
  }.bind(this);

  this.addSubItem();
  this.addSubItem();
  this.addSubItem();
}

function SubItem(num, root) {
  this.text = ko.observable("SubItem " + num);
  this.computed = ko.computed(function () {
    log("computing for " + this.text());
    return root.text();
  }, this);

  this.computed.subscribe(function () {
    root.timesComputed(root.timesComputed() + 1);
  }, this);
}

function Root() {
  var i = 0;

  this.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.addItem = function () {
    this.items.push(new Item(++i, this));
  }.bind(this);

  this.text = ko.observable("More clicked: ");
  this.timesComputed = ko.observable(0);

  this.more = function () {
    this.items.removeAll();
    this.addItem();
    this.addItem();
    this.addItem();    
    this.timesComputed(0);
    this.text("More clicked " + i);
  }.bind(this);

  this.more();
}

var vm = new Root();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[If you look at the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWVDu/6/), you will notice that the "log" contains an entry for *every single ViewModel ever created*. the computed property `SubItem.computed` is run even after I expected each of those items to be long gone. This is causing a serious degradation in performance in my application.

**So my questions are**:

- What am I doing wrong here? Am I expecting KnockoutJS to dispose of ViewModels that I actually need to be disposing of manually?
- Is my use of `ko.computed` on `SubItem` causing the issue?
- If KnockoutJS is not going to dispose of these viewmodels, how should I be disposing of them myself?

**Update:** After some further digging, I'm pretty sure the computed property in `SubItem` is the culprit. However, I still don't understand why that property is still being evaluated. Shouldn't `SubItem` be destroyed when the observable array is updated?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get to dig into this really, but observables store their list of dependencies, so the `root.text` has a reference to the SubItem's computed.  You can call `.dispose()` on a computed.  Also, you can pass in a `disposeWhen` function to a computed that gets executed every time that it is evaluated, but in your case it would need to access to its parent and root to determine if the parent had already been removed from the root's observableArray.  Probably better to proactively dispose.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and confirmation that it's the computed property--I know you can dispose of `computed`s in both of those ways, but it would be kind of hard for me to wire up a sensible `disposeWhen` function. As for calling `dispose`, I would have to find every single instance of the computed property and manually call `dispose`, which seems pretty cumbersome. It might be worth re-working my application to just *not* do this.

Comment: I agree that it is probably better to find a way not to structure it in this way. The computed will always have a dependency on `root.text`.  If you needed to do it, then I would probably put a `dispose` function on your `Item` that loops through the `SubItems` and disposes the computed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JavaScript garbage collector can only dispose a computed observable once all references to it and its dependencies are dropped. That's because observables keep a reference to any computed observables that depend on them (and vice versa).

One solution is to make the computed observable dispose itself when it no longer has any dependencies. This can be done easily using a helper function like this.

```
function autoDisposeComputed(readFunc) {
    var computed = ko.computed({
        read: readFunc,
        deferEvaluation: true,
        disposeWhen: function() {
            return !computed.getSubscriptionsCount();
        }
    });
    return computed;
}
```

Comment: The main issue in his case is that the computed would always have a dependency without some restructuring. I could see how it might be possible to work a `disposed` flag into the computed read function, so that it avoids gaining any dependencies when the flag is set.

Comment: True. He's using a manual subscription, and this method won't work in that case.

Comment: This does fix the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gWVDu/7/. I think I'm going to restructure my ViewModel hierarchy to get rid of that computed though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to clean dependencies to an observable so it would be catched by the garbage collector?