# Disposal function for Knockout dependencies

Tags: javascript, memory-management, knockout.js

I have a utility to augment an object to express the current ajax state as follows:

```
define(['ko'], function (ko) {
    var ajaxStatus = {
        success: 2,
        failure: -1,
        working: 1,
        none: 0,
    };

    return {
        ajaxStatusHelper: init,
    };


    function init(target) {
        if (target == undefined) throw new Error("Target cannot be undefined.");

        target.ajaxStatus = ko.observable(ajaxStatus.none);
        target.indicateSuccess = success.bind(target);
        target.indicateWorking = working.bind(target);
        target.indicateFailure = failure.bind(target);
        target.clearStatus = clear.bind(target);

        // computed properties
        target.ajaxSuccess = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.ajaxStatus() === ajaxStatus.success;
        }, target);
        target.ajaxFailure = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.ajaxStatus() === ajaxStatus.failure;
        }, target);
        target.ajaxWorking = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.ajaxStatus() === ajaxStatus.working;
        }, target);
        target.ajaxInactive = ko.computed(function () {
            return this.ajaxStatus() === ajaxStatus.none;
        }, target);

        return target;
    }

    // functions
    function clear() {
        this.ajaxStatus(ajaxStatus.none);
    }
    function success() {
        this.ajaxStatus(ajaxStatus.success);
    }
    function working() {
        this.ajaxStatus(ajaxStatus.working);
    }
    function failure() {
        this.ajaxStatus(ajaxStatus.failure);
    }
});
```

This utility might be utilized to extend multiple objects within the same view model object. For instance, I'll typically extend command members which make an async ajax call so that the view can display in icon indicating the result of the call on the command (with a KO binding not shown here).

**My question is what responsibility do I have for cleaning up these augmented nodes and what mechanism is in place to manage this cleanup.**

[According to Michael Best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14390713/1944699),

> The JavaScript garbage collector can only dispose a computed observable once all references to it and its dependencies are dropped.

Does this mean that I need to manually dispose these augmented members from the view model when the model is being disposed? Or will Knockout automatically delete all members when the associated UI elements are removed?

P.S. If it makes a difference, I'm currently using Knockout 2.3.0 but I'm working on migrating to 3.?

Comment: Why do you want to dispose of the observables? The whole point of observables is to bind them to the view so the view updates when the values change.

Comment: you want auto memory-managment on a model+view bundle. It sounds like knockout v3.2.0 new [component](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/) feature is designed for you.

Comment: @WayneEllery I don't actually *want* to dispose of the observables. My concern is that by not disposing them when the parent object is removed from the UI will result in a memory leak.

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually dispose of objects. If you change the model from one value to another then the old object will be removed from memory as long as nothing else refers to it.